# How to load a sprase numerical custom dataset into PyTorch?

Tags: python, scipy, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a custom numerical data set with 100k number of data points and 50M number of sparse features. What is the best way to load this data set into PyTorch?

I am looking for some function that loads a sparse matrix such as [scipy CSC matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) into sparse tensor.

Comment: What have you tried with `torch.sparse`?  It describes a `COO` input.  It's not identical to the `sparse.coo_matrix`, but close enough.  How did you construct the `csc` matrix?

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. I looked back to the torch.sparse and I see now that I can build the COO directly. I have the data in python data structures and I wanted to write it to a csc matrix as an intermediate data structure for reading into PyTorch.